# Use of 'Get' in a particular type of sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, get-passive

I just want to know whether the sentences below are grammatically correct or not –

> His / that attitude **gets** me irked.

Is the use of word 'get' acceptable in such cases?

> His / that attitude irks me.

Also, if correct, are these two sentences the same in meaning?

Comment: You should chose between "His" and "that", i.e. "His attitude..." or "That attitude...". Don't use both.

Comment: _Get_ in this context is rather informal, rather than ungrammatical. _Makes me [adjective]_ would be a more formal way to say it.

Comment: @KateBunting, Which one's more accurate? *That Makes me annoyed* or *That makes me feel annoyed*. Thanks!

Comment: There is no effective difference between 'being annoyed' and 'feeling annoyed'.

Comment: _Get_ is the inchoative/causative verb for both _be_ (_I got tired_ = _I came to be tired_) and _have_ (_She got a new car_ = _She came to have a new car_). So if something causes you to become irked, you get irked, and you are irked.

Answer (score 2):

'Get someone [adjective, perhaps modified]' is part of an object-orientated resultative construction:

- *These people really get me annoyed.*
- *Swimming also gets me really tired.*
- *That kind of behavior really gets me mad.*
- *The [lousy] service gets me annoyed every time.*
- *I can't backcomb and it gets me annoyed.*
- *What really gets me mad is that you aren't allowed to play football.*
- *It gets me down when a client is a no show.*
- *It gets me all fired up when I think about it.*

(All from the internet; corrected where appropriate.)

Some of these use it-clefts which would be awkward to rephrase, and one uses 'it' for 'this [fact]' [gets me annoyed].

But as with many strings using 'get', there are levels of informality which many would consider better avoided in formal contexts. 'Make' is often a convenient more formal replacement:

- *These people really make me annoyed.*

But 'mad', 'all fired up' are even less formal anyway, and 'It makes me down' isn't idiomatic.

Your example sentences are grammatical if in an informal register.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!